# Why do I need to use Paths.get() to get a Path? Why aren't there .delete(), etc methods on it?

Tags: java, filesystems, java-7, nio

[note: self answered question -- hope this will help you]

I need to do `Paths.get("/some/path/here")` to create a `Path`; why isn't there a `new Path(...)` constructor? In fact, why is `Path` an interface and not a class?

Also, why do I need to call `Files.delete(somePath)`? Why isn't there `path.delete()`?

Answer (score 2):

> Why do I need to use Paths.get() to get a Path?

This is because in Java 7, you can have more than one [`FileSystem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html); each `FileSystem` is provided by a [`FileSystemProvider`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileSystemProvider.html) and consists of one or more [`FileStore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileStore.html)s. And it is the `FileSystem` which procudes `Path`s.

`Paths.get(someStringHere)` is in fact equivalent to:

```
FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(someStringHere)
```

> Why aren't there .delete(), etc methods on it?

Because the logic to delete/create a path, determine its type has been moved into the `FileSystemProvider`. The vast majority of methods in [`Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) are therefore gateways between `Path`s and the `FileSystemProvider` they are issued from.

This allows for instance to `Files.copy()` a `Path` issued from your local filesystem to another which is issued, for instance, by a `FileSystem` providing access to an FTP server. Or even a ZIP file!